# How to check the validity of a FilePond component (using ngx-filepond)?

Tags: angular, validation, filepond

I'm using Angular FilePond ([ngx-filepond](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/frameworks/angular/)) together with the [file size validation plugin](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/file-validate-size/) and want to be able to prevent users from submitting when a file is too large.

The plugin shows the correct error message when a large file is choosen, but how should I best check the validity of the FilePond component instance before posting data to the server?

I've tried injecting the FilePond component using @ViewChild (as described [here](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/frameworks/angular/)), but the *status* property of the injected instance is always `undefined`, no matter if the file is valid or not so I'm uncertain whether this is the way to go.

The only way I've found to retrieve the validity status is to read the status property of the `onaddfile` event. It seems this property only gets set if there's a validation error?

```js
public postHandleAddFile(event: any) {
  console.log(event.status);
}
```

What is the preferred way of checking the validity status of the component?